# How to remove unwanted text extracted from the image?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, nlp, tesseract

I am working on a project called Business Card Scanner. I am extracting text from the image using pytesseract and then classifying the obtained text using regex and other techniques.

Whenever there is a logo in an image, tesseract consider it as a text and tries to read it. This results in a meaningless text. Consider the example of an image below:

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oLBD.jpg)

Here is what I have tried to extract the text:

```
# Google colab
# read required libraries
img = cv2.imread("img2.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5),0)
ret3, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2_imshow(thresh)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang = 'eng'); print(text)
```

This is what I get as output when I run the above code:

```
: eM , NOEs Efe: Mb fes fe y Ky TEP ON PILLS cag
gy: Ye Ws My Wii WL, FLY T by,

i igs Mg ER te EB iy MY, Gee.
: WO Ee as _ he i. "4 ‘; y sen “iy ye age i ‘ el HY tiber My, ee ered fi! ", ty Mf

Mm Gujarat TE og
: , fp bet
(x = Technological ( Wy, ey,

sae ae e . Tf) :
wage University ~~ es

e e é et

ikhil Suthar lees
fy Lg. Z - “fe " ‘Sa
. ve 7, of

Regional Coordinator - OSD MWe) Dh
ye

Mob. <hidden>

Email : <hidden>

Govt. Technical High School Campus, Near Aurobindo
Ashram Dandia Bazar,Vadodara - 390001, Gujarat, India
www.gtu.ac.in | www-gtuinnovationcouncil.2¢.in

i Ae

; ew, OD
t eS ft me ' @
ate
ary ya
j my

ee |
a
```

**Is there a way I can remove this unwanted text** that is produced due to logo (that's what I think)? Please let me know if my question require other information.

Comment: if the emailadres is real, you might want to hide it.

Comment: If you know where the logos are expected to be you can use the output OCR boxes to ignore them or you can blank them out before you call tesseract. Or you can crop/mask the image to leave solely the regions of interest. If you don't know where they you can use a dictionary (and a language) to filter out the gobbledegook.

Comment: @jtlz2 Unfortunately, the position of logo changes from image to image. It's not fixed. I can't make it static.

Comment: @Rohan Run an image detector first, locate the logo and mask it out.

Comment: Or filter out non-dark regions if text usually dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background of the image is the problem. You can omit by selecting a height-range

For example: If you select the height-range between: `h/4 - (3*h)/4`, result will be: (image is resized due to exceeding 2MiB.)

[image]

When you read:

```
Nikhil Suthar
Regional Coordinator - OSD

Email | Mob. |

Govt. Technical High School Campus, Near Aurobindo
Ashram Dandia Bazar, Vadodara - 390001, Gujarat, India
www.gtu.ac.in | www.gtuinnovationcouncil.ac.in
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("Oa9svHu.jpeg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = gry[int(h/4):int((3*h)/4), 0:w]
txt = image_to_string(gry)
print(txt.strip())
cv2.imshow("gry", gry)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ahx. Your approach works for this image. But, I have multiple images (all with same dimensions - (3000, 4000, 3)) and if I use the same height range (0.25 - 0.75), some images gets cropped resulting in loss of information. Is there any other way to remove the background? I tried drawing contours to get 4 coordinates of rect. using approxPolyDP and then applying perspective transformation, but I couldn't get those four coordinates around the card. Instead, it detects some other rectangle and not the card boundaries.

Comment: I would like to suggest reading [image-background-removal-using-opencv](https://medium.com/@chris.s.park/image-background-removal-using-opencv-part-1-da3695ac66b6)